# android button disappears from the screen

Tags: android, button

i am designing for the button using the icon samples, and wish that when icon is not pressed, it is black, and become white when it is pressed. Coding as follows:

### in layout xml:

```
<Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:background="@drawable/icon_new_btn"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"                
     android:id="@+id/newBtn" />
```

### in icon_new_btn.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >         
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
            <solid android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_new_white"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>> 
        </shape>    
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">            
            <solid android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_new"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>                        
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

### Question1 (seem to be solved using the below modification):

The whole button becomes invisible on the screen (it can still be pressed at that screen location!). How could I modify the above coding for meeting the purposes defined? Thanks!!

### Modification but new Question (Question2):

The following modified layout and selector seem to be solving the above Question 1. Yet the resolution become much poorer and icon distorted and looks bigger. See the below screenshot for the first and second icon using the below modified codes (icon 3 to 6 are simply using `android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_save"`  without any pressing effect and showing higher resolution):

[image]

### modified layout

```
    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_new_btn"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"                
            android:id="@+id/newBtn" />
```

### modified selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_new_white"
          android:state_pressed="true" />    

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_new" />
</selector>
```

Comment: First the add text in button

Comment: u mean to         <Button
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="new"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_new_btn"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"                
                android:id="@+id/newBtn" />?

Comment: get rid of  android:background="@android:color/transparent" fromt the both items of the  xml and add it to the button see if that fix the issue

Comment: Also change android:drawableTop to android:drawable

Comment: a faint white button appears...it is the default button look, but no icon_new.png showing...

Comment: For transparent instead     android:background="@android:color/transparent" use android:background="null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your graphic is being distored is because it being set as the background. To resolve this, you can instead use an `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_new_btn"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/newBtn" />
```

Also, you had specified `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. You might instead want `android:scaleType="centerInside"`.

Comment: Glad it helped! (And that it worked, because I typed it blindly from my phone...)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm posting the answer for you .
  create 4 xml files in res/layout.

state.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Button Focused-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@layout/state1"
            />
<!-- Button Focused Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="true"
            android:state_pressed="true"
             android:drawable="@layout/state1"
            />
<!-- Button Pressed-->
    <item   android:state_focused="false"
            android:state_pressed="true"
             android:drawable="@layout/state1"
            />
<!-- Button Default Image-->
    <item   android:drawable="@layout/state2"/>

</selector>
```

state1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" shape="rectangle">
<!--this is to give gradient effect -->
<gradient   android:angle="270"
               android:startColor="#6b6b6b"
               android:endColor="#0e0e0e"
               />
<!-- this is make corners of button rounded -->
<corners    android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
               android:topRightRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"/>

</shape>
```

state2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" shape="rectangle">
<!--this is to give gradient effect -->
<gradient   android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#e7ff47"
            android:endColor="#90a501"
            />
<!-- this is make corners of button rounded -->
<corners    android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
               android:topRightRadius="5dip"
               android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"/>

</shape>
```

In activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="183dp"
        android:text="Click Here To Change Color" 
        android:background="@layout/state"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.getimage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

thats all enjoy coding:)

Comment: It's bad practice to put drawable resources in the `res/layout` directory. Use `res/drawable` instead and reference them accordingly.

Comment: @ Rakesh L: Thanks for your example but Paul Lammertsma's solution is a bit simplier and can solve my problem...all in all, many thanks for your great help too! Happy coding!